# Phalcon validation doesn't work not in model

Tags: php, validation, phalcon

I can't understand why this code doesn't work

```
use Phalcon\Validation;
use Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Email as Email;

class LoginController extends ApiController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $validation = new Phalcon\Validation();

        $validation->add('email', new Email([
            'field' => 'email',
            'message' => 'wrong email'
        ]));

        //same add

        $messages = $validation->validate($_POST);

        ...
    }
}
```

in result $messages == empty array even if 'email' field is wrong

```
$validation->validate($_POST);
```

do nothing. what wrong?

In this case i need validation not in  model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

delete this one if you are still calling full path in  your code.

```
use Phalcon\Validation;
```

also change this:

```
use Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Email as Email;
```

to simply:

```
use Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Email;
```

and you should be able to use it as this:

```
$validation = new Phalcon\Validation();
$validation->add('email', new Email(array(
   'message' => 'The e-mail is not valid'
)));

$messages = $validation->validate($_POST);
if (count($messages)) {
    foreach ($messages as $message) {
        echo $message, '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I decided to put validation in a separate of the model, where I have all turned out after an hour of battle with code)